# High Database Instance Uptime for no queries

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have set up a Wordpress site on google appengine for PHP according to the instructions at https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress

I also have a CDN sitting in front of my site so the load on the Google App Engine instance is tiny. Really just cron jobs and the CDN updating it's cache. Here are the access logs fro the last 7 hours for an example.

```
2013-08-29 06:09:12.829 /post-sitemap.xml 200 6793ms 0kb Amazon CloudFront
2013-08-29 06:09:05.727 /robots.txt 200 4ms 0kb Amazon CloudFront
2013-08-29 04:55:07.937 /wp-cron.php 200 7206ms 0kb AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)
2013-08-29 04:33:59.915 /tag/javascript/ 200 8822ms 37kb Amazon CloudFront
2013-08-29 04:33:59.914 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ
2013-08-29 01:12:03.214 / 200 8751ms 39kb Amazon CloudFront
2013-08-29 01:12:03.214 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ
2013-08-29 01:11:50.755 /robots.txt 200 64ms 0kb Amazon CloudFront
2013-08-29 00:05:27.592 /sitemap_index.xml 200 7316ms 1kb Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
2013-08-29 00:05:20.217 /robots.txt 200 4ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
2013-08-28 23:30:45.596 /system/feeds/sitemap 301 179ms 0kb Amazon CloudFront
```

My problem is that despite this tiny load my Cloud SQL instance is online way too much and even though I would expect my usage charges under this scenario to be tiny, they are not, I am looking at having to commit to a package to keep them under control rather than paying by usage.

See The following graph for instance uptime that ends at 6am (log time) (10pm UTC)

[image: Instance Uptime]

Then look at the query load for the same period

[image: Query Load]

My guess at what is happening is that a database connection is being opened as soon as the google app engine instance is started (whether it is serving static or dynamic objects).

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Comment: +Sudsy send me your app_id and we'll take a look. We only open the connection to CLoudSQL when you app requests it, not when the instance is started - for example when starting your instance we have no idea what cloud sql instance your app is communicating with.

Comment: Thanks, my app_id is lighthouse-logic

Comment: I probably need the CloudSQL instance ID as well.

Comment: Duh! lighthouse-logic:wordpressll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloud SQL query graph was misleading.
Your application was getting queries throughout the day, which resulted in a hit on the database roughly every hour. This caused the database to be up for about half the time. The problem will be solved in a forthcoming version of the Cloud Console (cloud.google.com/console).

Sorry for the confusion

Joe Faith,
Product Manager,
Google Cloud SQL

Comment: Is there a way to get a log of the queries that have been running?